# Dealing with two version of the same package

Tags: python

I am using Python 2.7. I have a package already installed in my site-packages . But, i want to work with another version of the same package with the same package name.

```
import packagename
```

However, it is not installed in site-packages, but i placed it in some directory. Whenever i import it in python, It uses the version from site-packages. how do i use the one from a specific directory? Should i just change the folder name of the package or is there any other way?

Comment: Have you looked into using `virtualenv`s?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using a virtualenv you  can insert into the path before `site-packages`:

```
 import sys sys.path.insert(1,"path_to_directory")
```

You can add it to your `PYTHONPATH`, if you are using linux it would be something like `export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/your_dir/` in your `.bashrc`.